# XPath in T-SQL to select an entity

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath

I have a table, entities with an XML field (Descriptor) like this:

```
<component uid="a1">
  <files>
    <group name="component">
      <file path="a1.bmp" md5="0315DBA4FBEEB917F41AFF1A1BFF549B" />
      <file path="a2.jpg" md5="C3107D8BFA0EF0C02434FB7FC7472EAC" />
      <file path="a3.bmp" md5="603B9635A4921C25D50844254A2B573D" />
      <file path="a4.ini" md5="9C12CC7F5C1F1F4240DA407F7E3B145E" />
    </group>
  </files>
</component>
```

I want to find entities which has a 'file' with a specific md5 value:

```
select ... from ...
where Descriptor.value('(/component/files/group/file/@md5)[1]',
         'nvarchar(100)')='C3107D8BFA0EF0C02434FB7FC7472EAC'
```

The problem is that it finds the item when the 1st file has the specific md5 value. What I want is to find when **any of the file items** has the specific md5 value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the XML-method `exist()` to check simply for the existance of an element

I use a declared table variable to *mock-up* your scenario. Inserting three differing cases:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(EntityID INT IDENTITY,SomeText VARCHAR(100),Descriptor XML);
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
('MD5 03... on first place',
N'<component uid="a1">
  <files>
    <group name="component">
      <file path="a1.bmp" md5="0315DBA4FBEEB917F41AFF1A1BFF549B" />
      <file path="a2.jpg" md5="C3107D8BFA0EF0C02434FB7FC7472EAC" />
      <file path="a3.bmp" md5="603B9635A4921C25D50844254A2B573D" />
      <file path="a4.ini" md5="9C12CC7F5C1F1F4240DA407F7E3B145E" />
    </group>
  </files>
</component>')
,('MD5 03... somewhere',
N'<component uid="a1">
  <files>
    <group name="component">
      <file path="a2.jpg" md5="C3107D8BFA0EF0C02434FB7FC7472EAC" />
      <file path="a3.bmp" md5="603B9635A4921C25D50844254A2B573D" />
      <file path="a1.bmp" md5="0315DBA4FBEEB917F41AFF1A1BFF549B" />
      <file path="a4.ini" md5="9C12CC7F5C1F1F4240DA407F7E3B145E" />
    </group>
  </files>
</component>')
,('MD5 03... not existing',
N'<component uid="a1">
  <files>
    <group name="component">
      <file path="a2.jpg" md5="C3107D8BFA0EF0C02434FB7FC7472EAC" />
      <file path="a3.bmp" md5="603B9635A4921C25D50844254A2B573D" />
      <file path="a4.ini" md5="9C12CC7F5C1F1F4240DA407F7E3B145E" />
    </group>
  </files>
</component>');
```

This is a hardcoded query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @dummy
WHERE Descriptor.exist('/component/files/group/file[@md5="0315DBA4FBEEB917F41AFF1A1BFF549B"]')=1;
```

But you might want to introduce the search value as a sql variable parameter

```
DECLARE @md5 VARCHAR(100)='0315DBA4FBEEB917F41AFF1A1BFF549B';
SELECT * 
FROM @dummy
WHERE Descriptor.exist('/component/files/group/file[@md5=sql:variable("@md5")]')=1;
```

If this MD5 can be located in different places you might want to check the *deep search* too

```
DECLARE @md5 VARCHAR(100)='0315DBA4FBEEB917F41AFF1A1BFF549B';
SELECT * 
FROM @dummy
WHERE Descriptor.exist('//file[@md5=sql:variable("@md5")]')=1;
```

### Hint

Searching through XML-data will never be performant... I'd strongly advise - if you need this more often and if performance matters, to maintain a side table with MD5-values and rowIDs. You can use similar to an index. I would not go the XML-index road...

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It works! :) Meanwhile I remembered the .exist() function, but you were faster than me to figure out the correct syntax! I got stuck for some reason with the Descriptor.exist('//component/files/group/file/@md5="C7EBFC25E2A57D5C622722C9708600AF"')=1 form, but it was true for all entities, not just the ones with the md5 value.

Comment: Once again a comprehensive answer +1 .  Also saw the Danube River was frozen ... has to be a rare event.  http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4148890/One-Europe-s-longest-rivers-freezes-over.html

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thx :-) Hi, yes, it's quite cold outside. But the pictures are misleading... As a prevention of high-water-damage there are [two danubes going through Vienna](https://www.google.at/maps/@48.1951048,16.4081266,4457a,20y,40.67t/data=!3m1!1e3). The real danube river is frozen, but not smooth enough for skating. The second stream bed is standing water, in summer used for swimming, which is freezing quite often in winter.